# How to programmatically Find app installed in windows phone 8.1/URI association

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm building the windows phone app to find some third party apps installed on device. after doing research i found that it is not possible in windows phone.
as an alternative i'm using URI/protocol association to launch the third party app so that in async callback i could get whether app is launched or not(true/false). now the issue is, if the third party app is not installed on device it will redirect to store to download the app and in async callback it returns true.
how to make this uri association search only installed apps and do not search in the store.

Thanks,
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

I think it is against the sandbox philosophy of "Windows store apps" for Windows versions 8 and up, to allow this kind of knowledge exchange between applications.

One workaround is if you can have the *other app* make a note somewhere, on "the cloud" for instance, that it's installed.

Comment: Thank you Falken, can you please guide more about your workaround.

Comment: @Ajaykumar, you may have to ask for permission to read the users email address or other unique information in *both* apps, then send this information along with application id to a web service of yours.